# xaringan::summon_remark() without internet connection from R

Tags: r, xaringan, remarkjs

I create some slides using the `xaringan` package. But when I knit the file by hitting the RStudio "Knit" Button, only a white window appears.

Opening the generated html file with my browser shows the presentation as expected. Thus, I figured that the `moon_reader` from the package can't find `remark.js`. I also found out that one can download `remark.js` with `xaringan::summon_remark()`.

Unfortunately, this does not work for me since I do not have internet access from within R due to security restrictions at my institution.

Is there any other workaround which makes it possible to use the `moon_reader`?

Answer (score 2):

`xaringan::summon_remark()` basically downloads a version of `remark.js` using R. You can certainly use other methods to download it, e.g., just save https://remarkjs.com/downloads/remark-latest.min.js to a local directory using your web browser, and point the `chakra` option of `xaringan::moon_reader()` to the local path of `remark.js`.

Other versions of remark.js can be found at https://github.com/gnab/remark/tree/gh-pages/downloads.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It lead me to your great RMarkdown Guide: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/some-tips.html#working-offline.

Comment: That's weird. It worked exactly once... any ideas what else could go wrong?

Comment: I noticed today that it actually does work, it just renders really slow (like a minute or so). Might that be related to fonts which are not found? 

Does searching for them take very long if there is not internet connection?